# A smooth simple closed curve on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the boundary of a regular domain

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

Hello I am self studying differential geometry. I am working on the following problem.

Let $\sigma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ a smooth simple closed curve on the plane; show that the image of $\sigma$ is the boundary of a regular domain.

I could not give a complete solution, my attempt is the following.

Since $\sigma$ is a regular curve there exists a finite family of open sets $\{ U_{i}\}_{i=1}^{m}$ such that $\sigma([0,1])\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}U_{i}$ and on each open set $U_{i}$ there exists a diffeomorphism $\varphi_{i}$ such that
$$ \varphi_{i}(U_{i} \cap \sigma([0,1])) \subseteq \{x_{2}=0\} $$ and
$$ \varphi_{i}(U_{i} \cap \sigma([0,1])^{c} ) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}.$$
Then I observed that the family of open sets $ \{U_{i}\}_{i=1}^{m} \cup \{\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus \sigma([0,1]) \}$ admits a partition of unity $\{\psi_{i}\}_{i=0}^{m}$ and I have defined the function $\sigma: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ as
$$ \sigma(p):=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\psi_{i}\, \varphi_{i}^{2},$$
where $\varphi_{i}^{2}$ is the $2-$nd component of the diffeomorphism $\varphi_{i}.$ So I defined the set
$$ S=\{ p \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: \sigma(p)>0 \}$$ but I could not prove that $S$ is a regular domain, I suspect that I chose the wrong function.

Comment: Where did this exercise come from, and what material has been covered in the source? My personal approach would be to use some basic differential topology — see the proof of Jordan-Brouwer separation (in greater generality) in Guillemin and Pollack.

Answer (score 0):

What are the ground rules? Are you allowed to use the Jordan Curve Theorem? In your case of a smooth curve, the JCT can be proved from scratch, and the concepts involved in that proof might be what you need to finish your proof.

Suggestion:  Google " JORDAN CURVE THEOREM FOR
PIECEWISE SMOOTH CURVES" and you may find a helpful exposition by Pederson.

Comment: no in the book I'm studying Jordan curve theorem is not mentioned. I've thought it had something to do with this problem, but I also thought I could circumvent it. I'll check the references you gave me thanks.

Comment: I did not find anything, the only links I have found are from a university of Rome but they are not currently working. But I will check the proof somewhere else.